# Multi-variable function Integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

I want to calculate this integral.

$$ \int\int_B x^2y \space dx dy$$ where $$B = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 
 y \leq x \leq y^2+1,  0 \leq y \leq 1 \}$$

Now from the definition we know that the "$y$"-integral needs to be from $0$ to $1$.

I have tried to calculate it like this

$$ \int_0^1 \int_y^{y^2+1}x^2y \ \  dx dy$$

But since I know the answer to be $-\frac{1}{40}$ I knew I was wrong when I got $\frac{127}{120}$ as an answer, so I know I did something wrong with the limits.

Can someone help me ? I have done the calculation on paper, and its too long to type it in here as it is incorrect.

Here are the various steps I did as proof for my work:

$$ \int_0^1 \int_y^{y^2+1}x^2y \ \  dx dy$$

$$ \int_0^1  \left[ \frac{1}{3} x^3y \right]^{x=y^2+1}_{x=y} dy$$

$$ \int_0^1   \left(\frac{1}{3} (y^2+1)^3y \right) -  \left(\frac{1}{3}y^4 \right) dy$$

$$  \left[ \frac{1}{24} y^8 + \frac{1}{4}y^4+ \frac{1}{3}y^3 +\frac{1}{2}y^2 -\frac{1}{15}y^5 \right]^1_0   =\frac{127}{120}          $$

Comment: I just double checked and the example solution says $-\frac{1}{40}$ and $ \ldots y^2 +1$

Comment: I see a typo in your work. Going from the second to the third line, when you substitute $x=y^2+1$, you need the third line in the integral to be a $y$, not an $x$.

Comment: thanks for spotting the error

Comment: So your last line should be $\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{3y^4}{4}-\frac{y^5}{5} + \frac{y^6}{2}+ \frac{y^8}{8} \right)\Big|_0^1 = \frac{67}{120}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 
$$B = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \leq x \leq y^2,  0 \leq y \leq 1 \}, 
$$ 
then you should be integrating: 
$$
 \int_0^1 \int_{y}^{y^2} x^2y \  dx dy 
= - \int_0^1 \int_{y^2}^{y} x^2y \  dx dy   = -\frac{1}{40}. 
$$

But if 
$$B = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \leq x \leq y^2\color{blue}{+1},  0 \leq y \leq 1 \}, 
$$ 
then you should be integrating: 
$$
 \int_0^1 \int_{y}^{y^2+1} x^2y \   dx dy  
=  \int_0^1 \int_{0}^{x} x^2y \   dy dx   +  \int_1^2 \int_{\sqrt{x-1}}^{1} x^2y \   dy dx  
 = \frac{67}{120}. 
$$

Comment: sorry my domain definition was wrong, can you maybe give a little explanation why my version was wrong ?

Comment: @zython I see that you just changed the $x$-bounds for $B$. I will adjust my solution appropriately.

Comment: I have the feeling that I need to lear more on the topic, can you maybe suggest where I can learn more about the topic ?

Comment: @zython Most universities use Stewart's Calculus book when teaching Calculus III (multivariable calculus):  http://bit.ly/2vKX9C5 . Use any one of the versions to do problems and then post your questions and (attempted) solutions here. You can also use youtube as a resource to understand techniques, proofs, etc.

Comment: one more question if I may: what is this kind of task called so I can find more examples to better my knowledge ? I mean the one I tried to solve, is "double integral over a general region" correct, I ask because I couldnt find example tasks on the web that are like my example and I'm not from an english speaking country

Comment: @zython Yes, you are trying to do "double integrals over a general region". The geometric interpretation of what you are doing is this: if $f(x,y)\geq 0$ for all $(x,y)\in D$, then $\iint_D f(x,y)dA$, where $dA= dxdy = dydx$, should be interpreted as calculating the volume of the $3$-dimensional solid whose upper bound (surface) is given by $f(x,y)$, above the $xy$-plane, and above (restricted to) the planar domain $D$.